# PowerShell - How to get the value of PsObject property from an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexing, properties

**Edit**: Rephrasing question to be more clear

Here is the working code:

```
$arr = @(
    @('prop0','name0'),
    @('prop1','name1'),
    @('prop2','name2')
)

$obj = New-Object PsObject
foreach($innerArr in $arr)
{
    $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $innerArr[0] -NotePropertyValue $null
}

$obj2 = New-Object PsObject
$count = 0
foreach($innerArr in $arr)
{
    $value = 'val' + $count
    $obj2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $innerArr[1] -NotePropertyValue $value
    $count ++
}

for($i=0; $i -lt $arr.Count; $i++)
{
    # This is what I want to consolidate into one line
    # {
    $prop_name = $arr[$i][1]
    $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $arr[$i][1] -NotePropertyValue $obj2.$prop_name
    # }
}
```

How do I do this without assigning the name of the property to `$prop_name`?

The output of `$obj` should look like this:

```
PS C:\> $obj
prop0 : 
prop1 : 
prop2 : 
name0 : val0
name1 : val1
name2 : val2
```

Comment: Your first array is an array of two-element arrays. Perhaps it would be helpful if you explain what problem, exactly, you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart What? did you read the post? `$obj2.$arr[$i][1]` is killing it

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What problem dictates that data structure?

Comment: You cant do what you are thinking because it doesn't make since. You are turning a dictionary into a 2 d array

Comment: Guys, I made the question more clear. sorry about that... it was hard for me to phrase what I was asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you past the part you are erroring on :

```
$obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $arr[$i][1] -NotePropertyValue $obj2.PSObject.Properties.Item("name$i").value
```

The issue is your treating the PSobject like a array when it doesnt act like a array. Its more along the lines of a dictionary.

> Key : Value
>
> Key : Value
>
> Key : Value

Since there is no hierarchy you have to specify which Key you are looking for.

If I was going to do it i would go with something like

```
$obj2arr = @($obj2.PSObject.Properties | %{$_})
for($i=0; $i -lt $arr.Count; $i++)
{
     $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $arr[$i][1] -NotePropertyValue $obj2arr[$i].Value
}
```

Turning the PSObject into an array of Items and puling the property I want to use

Since your question has changed a little since i answered here is the script shortened

```
$arr = @(
    @('prop0','name0'),
    @('prop1','name1'),
    @('prop2','name2')
)
$obj = New-Object PsObject
$arr | %{ $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_[0] -NotePropertyValue $null}
$obj2 = New-Object PsObject
$count = 0
$arr | %{ $obj2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_[1] -NotePropertyValue ('val' + $count); $count++}
$obj2arr = @($obj2.PSObject.Properties | %{$_})
$count = 0
$arr | foreach-object{$obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ($_)[1] -NotePropertyValue $obj2arr[$count].Value; $count++}
$obj
```

Comment: Hey, I gave you an upvote. I made the question more clear. I just want to consolidate the last for loop to one line and I don't know how. I feel it is not necessary to first store `$prop_name` first